# Next Auth YouTube API invalid=[youtube.readonly]

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

My code frontend/src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.ClientId,
            clientSecret: process.env.ClientSecret,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    scope: 'openid email profile youtube.readonly',
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
};


export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1wx7.png)

Answer (score 0):

you should define completely with the googleapi url. example :

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

```
GoogleProvider({
  clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
  authorization: {
    params: {
      scope: 'openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
    }
  }
}),
```